# Spring thymeleaf implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hi can someone refer me or teach me on how do I implement thymeleaf in spring framework? I have a dynamic web project but all the tutorials I have seen uses maven. I am trying to work this for almost a week.

I have these beans:

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/Views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
  <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  <constructor-arg ref="servletContext"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
  <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1274)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:554)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use spring boot and maven

Comment: Option 1 is to go with spring boot with maven/gradle and Option 2 is to download the thymeleaf related jar files and add them in your project classpath and use.

Comment: Hi @SandeepRathore i've already done the option 2. i downloaded the thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE and thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE and include it to web-inf lib

Comment: Please refer these links
Link 1:  https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype/issues/72
Link 2:  http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Instantiation-of-bean-failed-nested-exception-is-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-Could-not-initializer-td4029070.html

Comment: @SandeepRathore the link is 404

Comment: updated...check now

Comment: move to spring boot, life is easier

Answer (score 1):

Check official Thymeleaf documentation - it explains explicilty how to integrate Spring with Thymeleaf

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html